# CodeIgniter 4 - how to remove hard-coded database connection value from the Database.php

Tags: codeigniter-4

By default in CI4 we put the database connection values like hostname, username and password directly inside the Database.php

Example:

```
$default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'adm',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'mydatabase',
        'DBDriver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => false,
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];
```

These values are kind of sensitive and attackers might able to obtain it if they somehow get the source code.

I try to declare a variable which value is passed in from other place and set it for the database connection value, but it seems like the configuration just allow string type.

So is there a way that we can get rid of using the hard-coded values inside this configuration? Or using any encryption method here?

Answer (score -1):

An Option is - You can use a `.env` file to get the hardcoded value out of it. Check [Dotenv File](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html#creating-dotenv-file)

Example

```
DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
....
```

In code

```
$default = [
    'hostname' => getenv('DB_HOSTNAME'),
    'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
     ....
];
```

Comment: So instead of storing passwords in a PHP file, that at least cannot be read through HTTP request, you propose to put it in a plain text file with a well-known name. Great idea

Comment: You should do exactly what the answer suggested. Check the link, so you have a better understanding, what is .env file used for. Don't worry, it is placed outside of your document root, so it won't be visible to anyone except your app.